# Number of variants of image produced after applying data augmentation with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am new to Tensorflow and was trying to apply data augmentation to my dataset using the `ImageDataGenerator`. Turns out that it has various parameters that the tensorflow backend uses to apply data augmentation to each image on the fly while feeding the image to the CNN. But no where in the documentation could I find the number of variations of each image that are generated as well as the total number of images fed to the CNN after the applying data augmentation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When called using .flow() method, the data generator will create one batch size of images for each iteration. This gives the total number of images fed to CNN.
The Keras documentation states for FLOW method :
" Takes data & label arrays, generates batches of augmented data."

https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-configure-image-data-augmentation-when-training-deep-learning-neural-networks/

Comment: Nice blog post. In the blog post, it states the following: **The images in the dataset are not used directly. Instead, only augmented images are provided to the model. Because the augmentations are performed randomly, this allows both modified images and close facsimiles of the original images (e.g. almost no augmentation) to be generated and used during training**. This seems to state that on the fly augmented images are passed to the CNN. Since only the augmented images are passed and none of the original ones, how do we get such great results just by passing augmented images?

Comment: As mentioned in the blog, some of the augmented images will be very similar to the images of the dataset and thus act as original images.

Comment: I get that, I need to know about the distribution of augmented images generated. Getting an exact number or a percentage would be really helpful.

Comment: Yes, I am also confused about the exact number of images generated and how it works. I will look deeper into the source code. It would be great to have better documentation on this.

Comment: @AlbertoTono id you find more info on this?